# Using MSBuild Command Line Reserved Properties

Tags: asp.net, msbuild

Is there a way to specify a command line property that contains a reserved property, for instance, $(COMPUTERNAME)?

```
$msbuild /p:ComputerName="$(COMPUTERNAME)"
```

The above doesn't resolve the reserved property $(COMPUTERNAME) into my actual computer's name (BMHEROLDW8) like it does with the default ComputerName property in my msbuild file's propertyGroup.

Comment: Are you trying to override the value...with something that is not actually the local computer name?  Or just get at the local-computer name?

Comment: I was trying to override the value with the current computername. I went a different direction, but still curious if it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ComputerName is a system environment variable that is automatically converted to an MsBuild property.

From the command line, you'd wrap the variable name in percent signs (or exclamations if in a batch file with delayed expansion enabled)

```
msbuild /p:ComputerName=%COMPUTERNAME%
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

Save this file as "OverrideEnvVariables.proj"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="AllTargetsWrapper" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <Target Name="AllTargetsWrapper">
        <CallTarget Targets="ShowOtherProperties" />
    </Target>

 <Target Name="ShowOtherProperties">  
    <Message Text="  " />
    <Message Text="  " />
    <Message Text=" Environment (SET) Variables*       " />
    <Message Text=" ---------------------------        " />
    <Message Text=" COMPUTERNAME = *$(COMPUTERNAME)*   " />
    <Message Text=" USERDNSDOMAIN = *$(USERDNSDOMAIN)* " />
    <Message Text=" USERDOMAIN = *$(USERDOMAIN)*       " />
    <Message Text=" USERNAME = *$(USERNAME)*           " />
</Target>

</Project>
```

Create a .bat file, and put this in, and run it.

```
set __msbuildExe=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe


"%__msbuildExe%" /target:AllTargetsWrapper OverrideEnvVariables.proj /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=AllTargetsWrapperNoOverride.log

"%__msbuildExe%" /target:AllTargetsWrapper OverrideEnvVariables.proj /p:ComputerName="Peanut" /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=AllTargetsWrapperWithOverride.log


set __msbuildExe=
```

The second run shows "Peanut" as the COMPUTERNAME.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was hoping for a way to pass in the parameter value via command line plain-text and have msbuild eval it. I'm using grunt.js and the msbuild package to execute the commands. Without a lot of rework to update/pass in an external file, I don't think this solution will work for me. It may be that what I'm asking for just isn't possible.